# How can user input a sequence of numbers into array// Java

Tags: java, arrays

so i've been trying to do this one thing which is letting user input his sequence number into array. I mean f.e. if he wanted to input 9901229976 and 9 would be Array[0], another 9 would be array[1], 0 would be array [2] and so on and so on, i've tried many things and didin't come up with the answer, i'm totally stuck with that, if the answer is so obvious i'm really, but i need answer as it is my project:(

Comment: What have you tried so far and how did it fail?

Comment: i tried putting it into string and take every number from it, tried using for loop but it meant putting numbers one by one, or loop like this, but i'm not if that's correct.  long [] pesel = new long[11];
            for (int i = 0; i<= pesel.length; i++)
            {
                pesel[i] = Long.parseLong(scanner.next());
            }

Comment: The answer is actually quite simple, but first, you should **attempt to solve the problem yourself**. Please post the code that you have tested. As I have seen other users say, Stack Overflow is not a free solution-writing service. You need to attempt the problem before you ask people to give you the solution.

Comment: Please post the code that you have attempted as part of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you would do it:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scanner.nextLine();
int[] array = new int[input.length()];

for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
    array[i] = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(input.charAt(i)));
}
```

1. `String.charAt(int position)` gets the Character located at a
   certain position in the String.
2. `Character.toString(Characters ch)`
   converts a Character to a String.
3. `Integer.parseInt(String s)` converts a String to an Integer.

So, what the code does is it goes through each character in the string, converts that character to a String, and then uses the `Integer.parseInt()` method in order to get that original character as a number.

`array` is now an array of the digits of the number that the user inputted. This should answer your question.

Comment: yeah, it works tho, but the thing is i was told to do an exercisice using resources that i've been taught, the problem is that i've never used Integer.parseInt not Character.toString, i can assume what second does but i'm not reall ysure what the integrer part does

Comment: Ok. So `Character.toString`, as you said, is very easy to understand. Converts a Character to a String. With `Integer.parseInt` it takes a String, and parses through it to find an Integer. So, to get an array of the digits, I had to go through each character in the string, convert it **to** a string, and then use parse int to get the integer in that position. I hope this answers your doubts.

Comment: Thanks, it is clear now and i appreacie the help and effort youve put:)